# Excel highlighting formula that changes criteria

Tags: excel, formula, highlight, conditional-formatting

I have 22 tables which all have the same parameters yet different values. Each parameter has the 20th, 50th and 80th percentiles derived (columns C-E) for the values present in columns F-M.

Examples:

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

I am trying to highlight all cells above their respective 80th percentiles without having to repeat a conditional format for every parameter in each of the 22 tables. For example, for calcium in Table 1, cells F8 and M8 are above the 80th percentile in cell E8 and should be highlighted. In Table 2 the calcium 80th percentile (Cell E36) is different and only J36 and K36 should be highlighted. I can do this by conditional formatting calcium 22 times (once for each table) but this would take forever as I need to do it for every parameter.

I should also mention that the tables are the exact same, meaning each parameter reappears every 28 cells (I.e. Table 1 calcium in A8, Table 2 calcium in A36, and Table 3 calcium A64 etc.).

let me know if that is not clear enough or you need more information. Any help appreciated!

Comment: conditional formatting for range F:M with `=F1<$E1` is not ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this vba script:

```vb
Sub Button_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim val80th As Double

    For row = 1 To 2000
        Select Case Range("A" & row)
            Case "Calcium", "Magnesium", "Sodium", "Potassium"
                val80th = Range("E" & row)
                HighlightValues row, val80th
        End Select
    Next row
End Sub

Sub HighlightValues(row As Integer, val As Double)
    For col = 6 To 13 ' 6 = col F // 13 = col M
        If Cells(row, col) > val Then
            Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```